# FIltering a data set in excel vba and pasting results into different tabs that are named based on filter

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter a data set in tab "Expiring Contracts", filtered on column B (this data set can increase or decrease based at any point). The different filters come from tab "Inputs" which can change overtime (increase or decrease). I am trying to paste the results of the filter to separate tabs that are named exactly like the list, BUT I want to paste the values on the next available (blank) cell. This is what I have now:

```
Sub ParseList2()

    Dim uwname As String
    Dim lastrowUW As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim N As Range

    lastrowUW = Sheets("Inputs").Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each N In Sheets("Inputs").Range("H2:H" & lastrowUW).Cells
        uwname = N.Text
        Sheets("Expiring Contracts").Range("$A:$AA").AutoFilter Field:=2, 
            Criteria1:=N
        lastrow = Columns(2).Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Range("A2:AA" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(uwname).Select
        lastrow = Columns(2).Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
        Range("A" & lastrow).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    Next N

    Sheets("Expiring Contracts").AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

This worked thanks to some comments below!

```
Sub ParseList2()

Dim uwname As String
Dim lastrowUW As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim N As Range
Dim rng As Range

lastrowUW = Sheets("Inputs").Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row


For Each N In Sheets("Inputs").Range("H2:H22").Cells
uwname = N.Value
Sheets("Expiring Contracts").Range("$A:$AA").AutoFilter Field:=2, 
Criteria1:=uwname
'lastrow = Columns(2).Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
Range("A2:AA99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(uwname).Select
lastrow = Columns(2).Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
Range("A" & lastrow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("Expiring Contracts").Select
Sheets("Expiring Contracts").AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A1").Select
Next N
Sheets("Expiring Contracts").Select
Sheets("Expiring Contracts").AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want to do. Please provide us with some examples showing the input and output

Comment: If you want to paste in the next available *blank* cell, you can use `.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` where column **A** would be the row you want to check for next blank cell

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Where is your code going wrong? I think we need a bit more information here

Comment: So really the only part of my code that isn't working is the For Each N loop.  It does not cycle through the list of Ns, rather it takes the first entry of the list, filters the larger data set using that entry, and then pastes the filtered data to each tab. What I want it to do, is take the first entry of the list, use that as the filter criteria on the larger data set, copy the range of filtered results, and past that range in the next blank cell on a tab that is named like the filter criteria.  Then move to the next criteria in the list and repeat.  Does this help @Ibo and @Maldred?

Comment: use `N.value` instead of `N.Text`

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do using VBA can very easily be accomplished using PivotTables and Slicers. Turn your source data into an Excel Table, make a PivotTable out of it, put the PivotTable in the Inputs tab, set up a Slicer on the field you want to filter on, put the other fields of interest in the PivotTable as row fields, and you're done. No code necessary. Let the application do the work for you.

Comment: Don't believe I can do this as other people will be editing the information that gets copied to their sheets (from the main data table), and once they are done editing, I will then need to recompile the list with their edits.

Comment: OK. In that case I have another solution that I will try to write up today.